# Is there a pure javascript implementation of IndexedDb?

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking to simplify some of my code which is implementing a pretty simple schema and I discovered this IndexedDb spec which isn't yet finalized.

The schema is used to present a table to the user with a filtering mechanism and allow the user to add/edit rows of the table. It doesn't need to stay persisted to the client (but that will make for less traffic when it is available). Thus I feel confident that I could use an implementation done fully in JS and could gain the benefits of a native implementation when it exists (presumably increased query speed and local storage).

I am aware of http://code.google.com/p/indexeddb/ but I am under a requirement to do this in such a way that nothing needs to be installed.

Have I gone mad or is there something to this?

Answer (score 0):

IndexedDB is not implemented in any major browser ATM. I think Firefox 4 may be testing it -- http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/06/comparing-indexeddb-and-webdatabase/

Edit: I didn't read -- you want a pure JS implementation; sorry.